# macro-producing macro invoked from another namespace :: Can't refer to qualified var that doesn't exist

Tags: macros, clojure

I have a macro-producing macro which I am trying to call from another namespace and it fails with "Can't refer to qualified var that doesn't exist".

I managed to reproduce it in the following code which is the simplest possible that exemplifies the problem. I also found a workaround, however I would like to understand the cause of the problem and whether some better solution exists.

## problem

#### file foo.clj

```
(ns foo)
(defmacro create-my-macro []
  `(defmacro my-macro []
      nil))
```

#### file boo.clj

```
(ns boo (:use [foo]))
(create-my-macro)
```

The above code when executed with:

```
java -cp clojure-1.4.0.jar clojure.main boo.clj
```

... fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't refer to qualified var that doesn't exist, compiling:(...boo.clj:2)
```

## workaround

For some reason, when the macro-producing macro is enhanced to accept a name for the macro to be created as a parameter, there is no failure.

#### file foo.clj

```
(ns foo)
(defmacro create-my-macro [macroName]
  (let [the-macroName (symbol macroName)]
    `(defmacro ~the-macroName []
         1)))
```

#### file boo.clj

```
(ns boo (:use [foo]))
(create-my-macro "foo")
(println (foo))
```

Running file boo.clj as above outputs a clean "1" on the console without any complains.

So, what was wrong in the first case and is there another way to fix it changing the macro-producing-macro to accept a name for the macro to be produced as a parameter? Also, why doesn't it fail when the macro-generating-macro is called from the same namespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a macro to introduce a symbol into the namespace in which it is run, instead of the namespace it is written in, you can use the combination of `unquote` and `quote` to get defmacro to produce a plain unqualified symbol at macroexpansion time

```
(ns foo)
(defmacro create-my-macro []
  `(defmacro ~'my-macro []
      nil))

boo> (my-macro) 
nil
```

the call to `(symbol macroName)` accomplishes very much the same thing by creating an un-namespace-qualified symbol from a string. You could use that same form in your first example:

```
(defmacro create-my-macro []
  `(defmacro ~(symbol "my-macro") [] 
      "new-result")) 

boo> (my-macro) 
"new-result"
```

Answer (score 1):

***'So, what was wrong in the first case and is there another way to fix it changing the macro-producing-macro to accept a name for the macro to be produced as a parameter?'***

What is wrong is that the macro is attempting to do something called 'symbol capture': it is trying to define a symbol that may end up overwriting an already existing symbol in the target namespace, and clojure is trying to protect you from the bugs associated with symbol capture.

If you are convinced that what you need is symbol capture then doing what Arthur Ulfeldt suggests above is what you need (using the unquote quote combination ~'my-macro)

But my recommendation to you would be to go with a variation of your initial solution and make explicit the fact that your macro will define a variable in the current namespace:

```
(ns foo)
(defmacro create-my-macro [macroName]
  `(defmacro ~macroName [] `1))
```

an invocation to your macro would look like:

```
(create-my-macro mymacro)
```

that would create a macro called 'mymacro which could then be invoked as follows:

```
(mymacro)   ;; would return 1
```

***'Also, why doesn't it fail when the macro-generating-macro is called from the same namespace?'***

not sure about this one but my guess is that as you are defining a symbol in the same namespace where the macro exist then it is assumed that you know which symbols are already in use and are responsible for not overwriting (capturing) symbols already used unintentionally. Whereas in the case of the invocation from a different namespace the symbol capture (if allowed) would be a surprising side effect to you. Again, this is just my guess.